# How can I show a small image and a paragraph by mouse hovering on another mapped image area?

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, imagemap

This will explain better what I want than my words:
http://jquery-image-map.ssdtutorials.com/
Even though the tutorial is available but it is done using image overlays in photoshop.
But I am highlighting my mapped image using a jquery plugin "jquery.maphilight.js".
Using that I have a mapped Image and it highlights over the mapped portion if I mouse hover on image.
How can I display a small picture and paragraph if a person hovers his mouse on a specific room (mapped portion).

Here is the javascript:

```
 $(function () {
        $(".mapping").maphilight();
        $("#mapping").css('visibility','hidden')

    $(".hoverable").css("border", "3px solid red");
```

& This is the html of image mapping:

```
<div class="mapping"> 
<map name="gmap">
<area shape="poly" id="cr1" coords="550,277,485,342,533,385,597,322" href="#" alt="cr1" name="room-1">
<area shape="poly" id="cr2"coords="579,246,627,200,672,246,624,290" href="#" alt="cr2" name="room-2">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [jQuery mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) event.

You would attach it to the 'area' tags on document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //this selector is selecting an element by the id of cr1.
    $('#cr1').on('mouseover', function(){
        //do your showing here
    });

    $('#cr1').on('mouseleave', function(){
        //do your hiding here
    });
});
```

for a generic handler you could do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //this is an attribute selector.
    //'area' is the typ of tag to match
    //[name indicates the attribute is named 'name'
    //^= indicates the attribute 'name' should start with the value following this operator
    //'room'] think of this as indicating the value of the name attribute
    // should match: 'room*'
    $('area[name^="room"]').on('mouseover', function(){
        //do your showing here, be sure to show only 
        //for the appropriate area. Maybe select on the id.
    });

    $('area[name^="room"]').on('mouseleave', function(){
        //do your hiding here. This could be generic unless you have
        //a multi-paragrah area instead of a single display area.
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, But I am a bit new to jquery. I don't know how to attach it to the area tags. just by mentioning the id of the area tag does not seems to work. In "do your showing here" i tried to load an image using <img> but its not working. Can you give a bit more detail on how to do it for just a single room ?
Regards

Comment: the jQuery selectors can be very confusing in my opinion.

Comment: $('area[name^="room"]') what is the "room" in this statement, a class or id of what ?

Comment: The brackets[] indicate an attribute selector. they follow the syntax: [{attributename}{special character}='{attribute value}'] The special character indicates how the attribute will equal the value. The ^ indicates that the attribute value starts with the supplied match value.

Comment: Alright, I have got it working without using javascript.
Do u think is there any difference in doing the same thing in html (mouse over) rather than doing in jquery ?

Comment: You could do this with pure CSS3 animations and attributes, however you are going to spend a lot more time coding it. You would set up @keyframes to show and then hide the paragraphs and images, then you would attach the animation triggers to the hover attribute of some element that can be hovered or a set of elements that can be hovered . Area tags don't support hover by default. So you would have to get creative.

Comment: After constantly trying , I have got that hover image using jquery mouseover function. The only problem left is that I am unable to change the position of the image that appears.  I want to bring it down but it is always at top of screen. How can I adjust its (and paragraph) positioning ?

Comment: Is the image modal? are you using position absolute? how are you displaying the image and paragraph? Could you post some code or make a fiddle? there are too many unknowns for me to be able to help with that. Sorry.

Comment: Its done now, I got it working by changing the position and margin of my wrapper class (the whole page content is enclosed in this div). Individually changing the position of each object was causing problem.

Comment: Well Thanks for the help, I have another question not related to this. I want to implement auto suggest feature on my site, basically it only has search option for Names of users (that retrieve from mysql database). There are so many ways to implement auto suggest, I am confused that do I just have to do it in simple javascript or I have to use any jquery plugin ?

Comment: there are a thousand ways to do it. You need to decide what kind of overhead is acceptable and what is within your skill set. There is no you have to do it this way or that, only will it be better for me if I do it this way or that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to make it work:
I created a div with "mouseover" and "mouseleave" attribute. and inside it I received the id of another element that I want to appear when I hover my mouse on this div.

```
<div  
    onmouseover="document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';"  <!-- element inside brackets will be shown-->
    onmouseout="document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';"> 
<area shape="poly" id="cr1" class="jTip" coords="550,277,485,342,533,385,597,322"
href="car_park_1.html" alt="cr1" name="room-1">
</div>
```

I posted my own answer so that it might also help others doing the same task :)