# How to change the position of an image that appears by mouse hover on a mapped image ?

Tags: html, css, position, imagemap, mousehover

I am doing something like this
http://jquery-image-map.ssdtutorials.com/
When I hover my mouse over an existing mapped image , the new image and paragraph comes but I am unable  to change their position. I tried using CSS but nothing works. They always appear at top right corner of the screen.
Help would be appreciated !

```
<div id="inside" 
    onmouseover="document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block';"  
    onmouseout="document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'none';">
<area shape="poly" id="cr1" class="jTip" coords="550,277,485,342,533,385,597,322"
href="car_park_1.html" alt="cr1" name="room-1">
</div><!-- element inside brackets will be shown-->
```

and here is the code for the image & paragraph to appear:

```
<div id="div2" style="float: left;">    <!--things to show on mouse hover appear here -->
<img src="fun_ahead.gif" class="thumb_cr1" height"100px" width="90" style="float:left;"/>
<p class="thumb_cr1"> hellooo </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hard to give an accurate answer without seeing all of your html/css. From what you've posted it's just the "float:left" on "div2" that is dealing with the position of the element.

Comment: Should I do the same thing using jquery?
But I don't know what to call in the jqeury mouse over function to display an image and a paragraph.. look here this is my actual question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976601/how-can-i-show-a-small-image-and-a-paragraph-by-mouse-hovering-on-another-mapped/13976767#13976767

Comment: You just call the container DIV ID e.g. jQuery("div2").show();

Comment: Thank you ,it works . One last thing, How can I change the position of the appeared image and paragraph to appear with my mapped image. It always shows at the top of the screen . I have tried css but that only shifts the image either left or right. but I am unable to move the picture down . It is always at the top of screen. what could be the issue ?

Comment: Look into absolute positioning. That is probably what you want to use for this.